# Want to ship two data tables in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, vb.net-2010

I've two data tables,

First one is to get data from excel(My source)
Second one is targeted data table, I'll fill second data table with the datas of first.

Later I'll send the second data table to SQL server.
My second data table is having the structure same as my table in SQL server,

So I want to plug first data table into second and pass second one to server for insertion.

I'll show the sample code,

I made this to an extent,

```
Dim dt1 As New DataTable
dt1.Columns.Add("Number", GetType(Integer))

' create another table with single column
Dim dt2 As New DataTable
dt2.Columns.Add("Number", GetType(Integer))

//This method is not fetching any data, but 

**For Each row In dt1.Rows
    dt2.ImportRow(row)
Next**

grvRecords.DataSource = dt2
```

My grid view(grvRecords) shows exact number of empty rows and columns. But no data in it.

Comment: how about using [`DataTable.Copy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx)?

Comment: No, my second table is structured one, i want data row wise from table ONE, because there are other values that is to be read from text boxes.

Comment: you mean you want to capture data from text box and club it with the data in datatable and then show it on Gridview? This sounds little wierd requirement.